# Tomcat System.out redirection

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, java.util.logging

We have got a legacy Java application, running on Tomcat. It logs its events in somewhat unconsistent way, sometimes even relying on System.out/err. These stdout/stderr records end up in catalina.log where they are mixed with "proper logged" events. We would like to separate the stdout/stderr log streams into separate files (and eventually get rid of them) but we don't know how to do it. The server runs default JULI configuration but we are open to any other option (such as SLF4J + Logback).

Comment: are you asking for advice on how to attach a logging framework to the app? Are you going to modify the application's source to redirect logs, or are you looking for a way to redirect it's logging after it's already been deployed (because that seems very difficult)

Comment: We are eventually going to modify the source (removing System.out.print and using proper logging) but for now I am asking for advice on deployment configuration. I would like Tomcat not to mix stdout/stderr into catalina.log but to send them to other files instead.

Comment: Then any advanced logging framework would do - log4j, slf4j+logback, log4j v2, ... just name the loggers uniquely, replace Syste.out/err println() with logging call and configure your log appenders to drop it into separate files.

Answer (score -1):

This explains it in full: [Log4J](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html) Just put log4j.jar and log4j.properties into WEB-INF/lib and WEB-INF/classes of your web application. Create a file called log4j.properties with the following content and save it into `$CATALINA_BASE/lib`

Example of log4j.properties that would cease output to stdout:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, yourapp

#Define all the appenders

log4j.appender.CATALINA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CATALINA.File=${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Append=true
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Encoding=UTF-8

#Roll-over the log once per day
log4j.appender.CATALINA.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.LOCALHOST=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.File=${catalina.base}/logs/localhost.
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Append=true
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.MANAGER=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MANAGER.File=${catalina.base}/logs/manager.
log4j.appender.MANAGER.Append=true
log4j.appender.MANAGER.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.MANAGER.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.MANAGER.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MANAGER.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.File=${catalina.base}/logs/host-manager.
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.Append=true
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

#Configure which loggers log to which appenders

log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost]=INFO, LOCALHOST
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager]=\INFO, MANAGER
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager]=\INFO, HOST-MANAGER

#You can define your Applog here: 

log4j.appender.yourapp=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.yourapp.File=${catalina.base}/logs/yourapp.log
log4j.appender.yourapp.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.yourapp.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.yourapp.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.yourapp.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] (%t) - <%m>%n
```

Hope this helps!